# Распределение слов по категориям

Tags: орфография, морфология

Как распределить слова по столбикам, орфограмма в корне, приставке, суффиксе: ласковый, смелость, утро, холодная, грустный, полеты, учитель, сосна, наклейка, весна, отлеты. Одно слово должно остаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В корне: х**о**лодная, грус**т**ный,  уч**и**тель (наверное,"и" после шипящих просится), с**о**сна.
В приставке: **о**тлеты, п**о**лёты.
В суффиксе: ласк**о**вый, смел**о**сть.

Утр**о** - в окончании. Это слово и осталось.